# SQL: To find consecutive repetitive characters in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find 4 or more consecutive repetitive characters in a column using SQL server. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

My data:

```
CompanyName
HSBC Inc
Barcccclays
AAAAA
Testtttt
Tesco Plc
```

My output should be as follows:

```
CompanyName
Barcccclays
AAAAA
Testtttt
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, text processing isn't a particularly strong part of T-SQL. Does this have to be done in the DB?

Comment: Yes, this is part of one of the rules for stewardship.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding strings with duplicate letters inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574990/finding-strings-with-duplicate-letters-inside)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but I would not do it in SQL Server without Regex function:

```
CREATE TABLE tabC(CompanyName VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO tabC(CompanyName) 
    SELECT 'HSBC Inc' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Barcccclays' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AAAAA' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Testtttt' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Tesco Plc';

WITH mul AS
(
   SELECT REPLICATE(CHAR(32 + N), 4) AS val
   FROM (select top 95 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
         from   master..spt_values t1)  AS s
)
SELECT *
FROM tabC c
WHERE LEN(CompanyName) > 4
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM mul
              WHERE CHARINDEX(mul.val,c.CompanyName) > 0)
```

**[RextesterDemo](http://rextester.com/XEF90901)**

How it works:

1) Generate replicated values like 'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc' and so on

2) Check if your string contains it.

Warning!

This solution checks only ASCII characters from 32 to 126.

**EDIT:**

> How can incorporate above code like this: select @flag = 1 from tabc where 1 = (WITH mul AS ( SELECT REPLICATE(CHAR(32 + N), 4) AS val FROM (select top 95 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N from master..spt_values t1) AS s ) SELECT * FROM tabC c WHERE LEN(CompanyName) > 4 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mul WHERE CHARINDEX(mul.val,c.CompanyName) > 0)).
>
> **I'm getting this error:If this statement is a common table expression, or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.** pls help

If you need to use it in context where you cannot use `CTE` change it to subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM tabC c
WHERE LEN(CompanyName) > 4
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM (SELECT REPLICATE(CHAR(32 + N), 4) AS val
                    FROM (select top 95 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
                          from master..spt_values t1)  AS s) mul
              WHERE CHARINDEX(mul.val,c.CompanyName) > 0)
```

Comment: Hi, How can incorporate above code like this:  select @flag = 1 from tabc where 1 = (WITH mul AS
(
   SELECT REPLICATE(CHAR(32 + N), 4) AS val
   FROM (select top 95 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
         from   master..spt_values t1)  AS s
)
SELECT *
FROM tabC c
WHERE LEN(CompanyName) > 4
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM mul
              WHERE CHARINDEX(mul.val,c.CompanyName) > 0)). I'm getting this error:If this statement is a common table expression, or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon. pls help.

Comment: Thanks so much! Much appreciated.

Comment: When I change EXISTS to NOT-EXISTS, it's giving me error: 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'. How could I correct this? TIA!

Comment: @user7617078 I suggest asking new question with your full query and sample data.

Comment: Sorry, Here is the code : SELECT *
FROM tabC c
WHERE LEN(CompanyName) > 4
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM (SELECT REPLICATE(CHAR(32 + N), 4) AS val
                    FROM (select top 95 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
                          from master..spt_values t1)  AS s) mul
              WHERE CHARINDEX(mul.val,c.CompanyName) > 0)

Comment: @user7617078 It is working http://rextester.com/OZBKIK11318 Both EXISTS and NOT EXISTS.

Comment: I have a stored proc which executes above query like this:

Comment: @user7617078 Please ask new question. This is not the way that SO works. Your original question has been solved.

Comment: Thanks! Posted a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the simplest solution would be to enable [SQL CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration) and implement your condition as [user-defined function in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.100).aspx). There you have the power of Regular expressions to use (ex: the [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) class).

The regex you would need would be along the lines of `(.)\1{3}`, which matches any character followed by the same charcter at least 3 times.

For example the UDF could be written in C# like this:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
    public static SqlBoolean ContainsRepeatingCharacters(SqlString input)
    {
        const String pattern = @"(.)\1{3}";     
        Boolean hasMatch = Regex.IsMatch(input.ToString(), pattern);
        return new SqlBoolean(hasMatch);
    }
}
```

You could then use it like any other UDF:

```
select companyName
from companies
where dbo.ContainsRepeatingCharacters(companyName) = 1
```

Implementing the same condition in pure TSQL is by all means possible just it would probably be a mess to read and maintain. For example, consider the brute force solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575084/331325) and think what happens when the desired condition should be changed in future even just a bit more complex.

Comment:  `Implementing same condition in pure TSQL is by all means possible just it would probably be a mess to read` as always it depends :)

Comment: A CLR is complete overkill for something like this. A good Ngrams function or Numbers table along with a basic understanding of REPLICATE and CHARINDEX is really all that's required.

Comment: @AlanBurstein, if requirements never change - maybe it is overkill. But I would say SQLCLR is an under-used feature and a little promotion for other similar problems is in order. If you are after productivity of maintainability then I would still prefer testing-debugging-changing SQLCLR over TSQL. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy of [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) handy this is a piece of cake. Both solutions below are simple, require no CLR integration, and will blow the doors off of any regex alternative with respect to performance.

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @table table 
(
  CompanyName varchar(100) 
  unique /* included to simulate an index on this column */
);
INSERT @table values('HSBC Inc'),('Barcccclays'),('AAAAA'),('Testtttt'),('Tesco Plc');

-- solution #1
SELECT companyname
FROM @table
CROSS APPLY dbo.ngrams8K(CompanyName,1)
WHERE charindex(replicate(token,4), CompanyName) > 0
GROUP BY CompanyName;

-- solution #2 (if you want to return a boolean)
SELECT companyname, has4ConsecChars = max(sign(charindex(replicate(token,4), CompanyName)))
FROM @table
CROSS APPLY dbo.ngrams8K(CompanyName,1)
GROUP BY CompanyName;
```

**Results**

```
companyname
---------------
AAAAA
Barcccclays
Testtttt   

companyname     has4ConsecChars
--------------- ---------------
AAAAA           1
Barcccclays     1
HSBC Inc        0
Tesco Plc       0
Testtttt        1
```