# T-SQL How to get all records where a specific char is repeated consecutively?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking a way to get all records where the `word` column consists entirely of a single letter repeated 2 or more times

Example:
In a table I have something like this:

```
id  word
1   house
2   dog
3   aaaa
4   eee
5   aaaaaa
6   car
7   aa
8   hook
9   arrow
10  oooooo
11  feel
12  tooth
```

I would like a way to do a query on that table and get only the ids: 3,4,5,7,10

I guess this is possible with an regular expression

Comment: Similar one, please refer to below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574990/finding-strings-with-duplicate-letters-inside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable
WHERE Word = REPLICATE(LEFT(Word,1),LEN(Word)) AND LEN(Word) >= 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need it to be able to identify only consecutive repeated chars. But this code is very interesting!

Comment: What makes you think this doesn't identify consecutive repeated characters? It returns `3`, `4`, `5` and `7` as requested in your question.

Comment: you are right, it does return them, but what i need is that ONLY returns the consecutive. I think i did make myself clear in my question, sorry

Comment: This does return **only** the consecutive. Your question asks for `get only the ids: 3,4,5 and 7` and that is exactly what this returns. Demo http://rextester.com/YAZUY36379

Comment: ok - now your edit makes things clearer - this is easier - and for the record your question was not clear. I have edited it to clarify it based on the example data.

Comment: @MartinSmith... what if we use of soundex() function that it would not find the correct result ??

Comment: @YogeshSharma - I doubt that it would. The `SOUNDEX` function was designed for categorising American  surnames in census data IIRC - not  this kind of task.

Comment: @MartinSmith... yes i can see The letters A, E, I, O, U, H, W, and Y are ignored

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes that's why i edited. I figured out that it wasnt clear enough

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank u so much! this works just fine! It is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Please use this. Set Based Approach**

```
;WITH SingleDigits(Number) AS
(
    SELECT Number
    FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8),
    (9), (0)) AS X(Number)
)
,Series AS
(
    SELECT (d1.Number+1) + (10*d2.Number) + (100*d3.Number) + (1000*d4.Number) Number
    from
    SingleDigits as d1,
    SingleDigits as d2,
    SingleDigits as d3,
    SingleDigits as d4
)
SELECT Id,Word
FROM
(
    SELECT Id,word,u,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) u1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Id,word,Charx,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Id,Word,Charx) u    
        FROM Wrds N
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT SUBSTRING(word,number,1) Charx , number
            FROM
            ( 
                SELECT DISTINCT number FROM
                Series WHERE number > 0 AND number <= DATALENGTH(N.word)
            )v  
        )t
    )z 
    GROUP BY Id,word,u
)x WHERE u1 = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Id          Word
----------- ----------
3           aaaa
4           eee
5           aaaaaa
7           aa
10          oooooo

(5 rows affected)
```

Read more from -

https://msbiskills.com/2018/02/16/sql-puzzle-names-with-non-repeating-characters-puzzle-sql-interview-question/

Comment: Almost, but i need that this query could identify only consecutive repeated letters.