# Where REGEXP Does work properly on normal regex

Tags: mysql

Im trying

That:

```
SELECT * FROM `db_name` WHERE `username` = REGEXP "/(.)(?=.*\1)/g"
```

and it returns no data, any walkarounds?

Well what im trying to get is, all data where the username contains duplicated letter or number , such as "x34x", "aafdgd"

the regex works properly on the language directly(PHP), but i want it to work at the database level.

Comment: No workarounds really, but [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574990/finding-strings-with-duplicate-letters-inside) for one option.  MySQL's regex engine does not support backreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what i did because i didnt find any solution is:

for the existing records:
i made new column (has_repeater), and i made an code that checks if it is repeated in regex ( php ), then it set value for true/false.

it auto sets (has_repeater) while adding the record.